# The AWS IoT Demo failed to connect with the MQTT Connect Message

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, tcp, mqtt, portforwarding

I am new here and I have got to do a project for university. I've been doing research for it since two weeks and I cannot proceed because of this connect error.

I use the AWS IoT Zero Touch Secure Provisioning Kit and I am trying to do the demo (http://microchipdeveloper.com/iot:ztpk).

I works fine until the device wants to connect to the Connect Message. Therefore MQTT is used.

I think the problem is the port forwarding in my router. I tried to forward the ports 8883 and 1883 to my device, but did not help. I also tried to forward it to my PC to test if it is working on pages like (https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/) but it seems like they are closed. I created a rule in my firewall and forwarded the ports in my router menu. Do you see a mistake?

[image: portforwarding]

Here you can see the error, the device produces when trying to connect to the Connect Topic.

[image: error]

Is it right to forward the ports to the device' IP like it is connected to my WiFi? And what could be the problem in the port forwarding for my PC, why is it not even working there?

Please excuse, that my knowleadge is not that much. I am student, but I need the information for the project.
Thank you very much!

Comment: You shouldn't have to forward any ports, as the MQTT connection is outbound to the AWS broker, normal NAT should just handle it. You may need to enable the firewall to allow outbound traffic on the correct ports.

Comment: the firewall of my router?

Comment: Yes, anything that could drop packets before it reaches the internet

Comment: Well, it can just be the router, but I cannot find anything in the menu. The device directly connects to the router via WiFi.. I thought the portforwarding is what you describe?